# Get list of keySets (policy keys) in a given Azure AD B2C tenant with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to figure out how to use Microsoft Graph API in order to get information on an Azure AD B2C tenant's Policy Keys. It seems like it should be possible given the following documentation, but I keep getting an `InvalidAuthenticationToken` error.

Documentation link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-get-started?tabs=app-reg-ga

What exactly do I need to do to call the endpoint shown in here (the /trustFramework/keySets endpoint)? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/trustframework-list-keysets?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

In postman, I'm simply firing off the get request with Basic auth using my Portal credentials. Am I going about this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment.** and received similar error  `*InvalidAuthenticationToken*`

---

[image]

---

Then , I checked that I missed to give authorization header with bearer token ,
Which Is required parameter to query that as per : [List keySets - Microsoft Graph beta | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/trustframework-list-keysets?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

***Below are the scopes , I have given admin consent to.*** delegated and application permissions  like `openid` `offline_access` `profile` `User.ReadWrite.All` `TrustFrameworkKeySet.Read.All` `Policy.ReadWrite.TrustFramework` `AuditLog.Read.All`

---

[image]

Do a get request at **`https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxx063/oauth2/v2.0/token`** to receive a token for the application endpoint in postman with the scope for graph i.e; ***`https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`*** , for that particular `tenant` (here used tenantId of azure ad b2c).

---

[image]

Give required values like client_id, client_secret for client_credential flow

Then try to query graph using that token :
**GET**  **`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/trustFramework/keySets`** ,
Following above steps with correct values and granting admin consent , I could successfully query the keySets

---

[image]

---

[image]